# IOS JSON sending an email from Mandrill

Tags: ios, json, email, mandrill

I have an IOS application that I would like to send an email via Mandrill. I have tried to implement this, but its not working and Ive confused myself.

When pressing the button to send an email from the IOS application I log this error message:

```
{"status":"error","code":-1,"name":"ValidationError","message":"You must specify a key value"}
```

My code is:

```
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"key\": \"abcdefg123456\", \"raw_message\": \"From: me@mydomain.com\nTo: me@myotherdomain.com\nSubject: Some Subject\n\nSome content.}"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-raw.json"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSLog(@"Post: %@", post);

NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks you forgot the \" after "content.".

Try to write your "post" variable as follow:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"key\": \"abcdefg123456\", \"raw_message\": \"From: me@mydomain.com\nTo: me@myotherdomain.com\nSubject: Some Subject\n\nSome content.\"}"];
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I did miss out the \ after content. Also I was required to add a \ before  every \n